# AttributeError due to Google Cloud Datastore when running python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-python

Ever since I installed Google Cloud's Python wrapper (using `sudo pip3 install google.cloud`), I've started seeing this error.

Every time I run a `python3` program, even if only using the interactive shell, I see the following error:

```
Error processing line 10 of /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/proto_google_cloud_datastore_v1-0.90.4-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 557, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
```

Everything works just fine in spite of the above error, but it's annoying to see a stack trace every time I run a `python3` program.

Comment: Can you show the code that's giving you the error? See this answer pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935698/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-loader