# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

having an issue today when I started up my laptop (Ubuntu 18.4) and trying to use pip to install packages, I'm met with this error:

```
Error processing line 3 of /home/cjones/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapis_common_protos-1.5.8-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 174, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 568, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
```

I don't think I changed anything since last successful boot but it seems as though something is missing... can anyone help?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Delete `/home/cjones/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapis_common_protos-1.5.8-py3.6-nspkg.pth` and retry.

Comment: Would be good to give an explanation on how this works? I had this error and was due to an old package that had been moved/renmaed, but the .pth file still pointing at the original location

Comment: I believe what they mean if you have an error `Error processing line 3 of file_name` just get rid of the `file_name`  causing error.

Answer (score 24):

I had the similar problem, but the error message referenced a different .pth file.  The error message I received was:

```
Error processing line 1 of /Users/jt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinxcontrib.datatemplates-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/jt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 580, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
```

Following the solution described here:

https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/95

I edited the .pth file (the file at the start of the error message, immediately after the text `Error processing line 1 of`) and added a newline character after the first semicolon.  That is, I changed:

```
import sys, types, os;has_mfs = sys.version_info > (3, 5);p ...<rest of file>
```

To:

```
import sys, types, os;
has_mfs = sys.version_info > (3, 5);p ...<rest of file>
```

I don't know why this worked, but it did.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error with my virtual environments on a mac, but referring to matplotlib:

> Error processing line 1 of //anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib-3.1.3-py3.7-nspkg.pth:

As in the previous answer, it was solved by changing the file mentioned:

```
import sys, types, os;has_mfs = sys.version_info > (3, 5);p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).$
```

to this, via a linebreak:

```
import sys, types, os;
has_mfs = sys.version_info > (3, 5);p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).$
```

Answer (score 3):

the line is too long for pip3 to process.
You can reinstall googleapis_common_protos to fix this problem.
it means you can run this:

> `pip uninstall googleapis_common_protos`
> and
> `pip install googleapis_common_protos`

Answer (score 1):

I had to do :0,$s/;/;\r/g in vi.

it looks like a line is too long for pip3 to process. Basically, some packages put all commands on one line and that overflows a buffer somewhere.

This vi command puts a carriage return after every semicolon. (It is possible a newline (\n) would work instead of a carriage return.)

Breakdown of the command:

```
: - use ED line editor command
0,$ - run on all lines
s - regular expression substitution
/ - delimiter start search
; - replace semicolon with
/ - delimiter end search start replace
;\r - replace with semicolon followed by carriage return
/ - delimiter end replace
g - global - do more than once per line.
```

This is a very common vi command. If you need to replace a "/", you can use another character as the delimiter - the first character after "s" is the delimiter

Comment: can you please be more clear in your instructions?

Comment: it looks horrible, please elaboarate

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and

```
> rm -f /Users/boss/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapis_common_protos-1.57.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth
```

solve the problem, for now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I seperated all lines with ; especially adding a ; where none was present.
For example: (p not in mp) and mp.append(p)
to
(p not in mp) and mp.append(p);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

SOLUTION - FIX:

1. https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/python3-pastescript_2.0.2-2_all.deb.html
2. Download: python3-pastescript_2.0.2-2_all.deb

Download: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pastescript/python3-pastescript_2.0.2-2_all.deb

3. Force Install:

┌──(chacka0101㉿kali)-[~/Downloads]

└─$ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite python3-pastescript_2.0.2-2_all.deb

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).