# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader' when starting Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

When I open the Anaconda 3 Prompt it is giving this on startup (see below). Some similar problems have received various answers which I find confusing to implement, could someone offer a step-by-step solution to this? (I believe it has something to do with matplotlib.) Thanks!

This link has the same question / answer, but I don't know how to delete the file path.

[AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935698/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-loader/56935782)

> Error processing line 1 of C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site->packages\matplotlib-3.1.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File >"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage exec(line) >File "", line 1, in File "", line 580, in module_from_spec AttributeError: >'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
>
> Remainder of file ignored