# Module not found in jupyter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, modulenotfounderror

I want to install scikit-learn. I have successfully installed it but still showing module not found. Then I tried to unistall and reinstall it. But while uninstalling I am getting like this. And I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935698/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-loader) but still getting the same error

```
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 553, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
```

Comment: `Error processing line 1 of C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.4.0-py3.8-nspkg.pth:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 553, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
Remainder of file ignored`               I'm getting like this while opening jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1):

Write the below code in your Jupyter notebook cell and it will not show the error again.

!pip install sklearn --user

import sklearn