# bash: cd: /home/user/.conda/pkgs: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda

I have had **the loader problem** with my **conda** similar to this post:

[AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935698/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-loader)

So when can not solve it i have decides to **reinstall** **conda** by These command :

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
sudo bash Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

So based of [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9876) post my **Conda** information is :

> ````
>      active environment : base
>     active env location : /home/so/anaconda3
>             shell level : 1
>        user config file : /home/so/.condarc  populated config files : /home/so/.condarc
>           conda version : 4.9.2
>     conda-build version : 3.20.5
>          python version : 3.8.5.final.0
>        virtual packages : __cuda=11.0=0
>                           __glibc=2.27=0
>                           __unix=0=0
>                           __archspec=1=x86_64
>        base environment : /home/so/anaconda3  (read only)
>            channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>           package cache : /home/so/anaconda3/pkgs
>                           /home/so/.conda/pkgs
>        envs directories : /home/so/.conda/envs
>                           /home/so/anaconda3/envs
>                platform : linux-64
>              user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.5 Linux/5.4.0-66-generic ubuntu/18.04.5 glibc/2.27
>                 UID:GID : 1000:1000
>              netrc file : None
>            offline mode : False
>
> ``` and `conda config --show-sources` is:
>
> ``` conda config --show-sources
> ==> /home/so/.condarc <== ssl_verify: True channels:
>   - defaults
>
> ``` and `conda list --show-channel-urls` is:
>
> ``` conda list --show-channel-urls
> # packages in environment at /home/so/anaconda3:
> #
> # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
> _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py38_0    defaults
> _libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main    defaults alabaster                 0.7.12                     py_0    defaults
> anaconda                  2020.11                  py38_0    defaults
> anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py38_0    defaults
> anaconda-navigator        1.10.0                   py38_0    defaults
> anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0    defaults
> argh                      0.26.2                   py38_0    defaults
> argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py38h7b6447c_1    defaults
> asn1crypto                1.4.0                      py_0    defaults
> astroid                   2.4.2                    py38_0    defaults
> astropy                   4.0.2            py38h7b6447c_0    defaults
> async_generator           1.10                       py_0    defaults
> atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0    defaults
> attrs                     20.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
> autopep8                  1.5.4                      py_0    defaults
> babel                     2.8.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
> backcall                  0.2.0                      py_0    defaults
> backports                 1.0                        py_2    defaults
> backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0   
> defaults backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                   
> py38_2    defaults backports.tempfile        1.0                      
> py_1    defaults backports.weakref         1.0.post1                 
> py_1    defaults beautifulsoup4            4.9.3             
> pyhb0f4dca_0    defaults bitarray                  1.6.1           
> py38h27cfd23_0    defaults bkcharts                  0.2              
> py38_0    defaults blas                      1.0                      
> mkl    defaults bleach                    3.2.1                     
> py_0    defaults blosc                     1.20.1              
> hd408876_0    defaults bokeh                     2.2.3                
> py38_0    defaults boto                      2.49.0                  
> py38_0    defaults bottleneck                1.3.2           
> py38heb32a55_1    defaults brotlipy                  0.7.0          
> py38h7b6447c_1000    defaults bzip2                     1.0.8         
> h7b6447c_0    defaults ca-certificates           2020.10.14           
> 0    defaults cairo                     1.14.12             
> h8948797_3    defaults certifi                   2020.6.20         
> pyhd3eb1b0_3    defaults cffi                      1.14.3          
> py38he30daa8_0    defaults chardet                   3.0.4            
> py38_1003    defaults click                     7.1.2                 
> py_0    defaults cloudpickle               1.6.0                     
> py_0    defaults clyent                    1.2.2                   
> py38_1    defaults colorama                  0.4.4                    
> py_0    defaults conda                     4.9.2           
> py38h06a4308_0    defaults conda-build               3.20.5           
> py38_1    defaults conda-env                 2.6.0                    
> 1    defaults conda-package-handling    1.7.2           
> py38h03888b9_0    defaults conda-verify              3.4.2            
> py_1    defaults contextlib2               0.6.0.post1               
> py_0    defaults cryptography              3.1.1           
> py38h1ba5d50_0    defaults curl                      7.71.1           
> hbc83047_1    defaults cycler                    0.10.0               
> py38_0    defaults cython                    0.29.21         
> py38he6710b0_0    defaults cytoolz                   0.11.0          
> py38h7b6447c_0    defaults dask                      2.30.0           
> py_0    defaults dask-core                 2.30.0                    
> py_0    defaults dbus                      1.13.18             
> hb2f20db_0    defaults decorator                 4.4.2                
> py_0    defaults defusedxml                0.6.0                     
> py_0    defaults diff-match-patch          20200713                  
> py_0    defaults distributed               2.30.1          
> py38h06a4308_0    defaults docutils                  0.16             
> py38_1    defaults entrypoints               0.3                     
> py38_0    defaults et_xmlfile                1.0.1                  
> py_1001    defaults expat                     2.2.10              
> he6710b0_2    defaults fastcache                 1.1.0           
> py38h7b6447c_0    defaults filelock                  3.0.12           
> py_0    defaults flake8                    3.8.4                     
> py_0    defaults flask                     1.1.2                     
> py_0    defaults fontconfig                2.13.0              
> h9420a91_0    defaults freetype                  2.10.4              
> h5ab3b9f_0    defaults fribidi                   1.0.10              
> h7b6447c_0    defaults fsspec                    0.8.3                
> py_0    defaults future                    0.18.2                  
> py38_1    defaults get_terminal_size         1.0.0               
> haa9412d_0    defaults gevent                    20.9.0          
> py38h7b6447c_0    defaults glib                      2.66.1           
> h92f7085_0    defaults glob2                     0.7                  
> py_0    defaults gmp                       6.1.2               
> h6c8ec71_1    defaults gmpy2                     2.0.8           
> py38hd5f6e3b_3    defaults graphite2                 1.3.14           
> h23475e2_0    defaults greenlet                  0.4.17          
> py38h7b6447c_0    defaults gst-plugins-base          1.14.0           
> hbbd80ab_1    defaults gstreamer                 1.14.0              
> hb31296c_0    defaults h5py                      2.10.0          
> py38h7918eee_0    defaults harfbuzz                  2.4.0            
> hca77d97_1    defaults hdf5                      1.10.4              
> hb1b8bf9_0    defaults heapdict                  1.0.1                
> py_0    defaults html5lib                  1.1                       
> py_0    defaults icu                       58.2                
> he6710b0_3    defaults idna                      2.10                 
> py_0    defaults imageio                   2.9.0                     
> py_0    defaults imagesize                 1.2.0                     
> py_0    defaults importlib-metadata        2.0.0                     
> py_1    defaults importlib_metadata        2.0.0                      
> 1    defaults iniconfig                 1.1.1                     
> py_0    defaults intel-openmp              2020.2                     
> 254    defaults intervaltree              3.1.0                     
> py_0    defaults ipykernel                 5.3.4           
> py38h5ca1d4c_0    defaults ipython                   7.19.0          
> py38hb070fc8_0    defaults ipython_genutils          0.2.0            
> py38_0    defaults ipywidgets                7.5.1                    
> py_1    defaults isort                     5.6.4                     
> py_0    defaults itsdangerous              1.1.0                     
> py_0    defaults jbig                      2.1                 
> hdba287a_0    defaults jdcal                     1.4.1                
> py_0    defaults jedi                      0.17.1                  
> py38_0    defaults jeepney                   0.5.0             
> pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults jinja2                    2.11.2             
> py_0    defaults joblib                    0.17.0                    
> py_0    defaults jpeg                      9b                  
> h024ee3a_2    defaults json5                     0.9.5                
> py_0    defaults jsonschema                3.2.0                     
> py_2    defaults jupyter                   1.0.0                   
> py38_7    defaults jupyter_client            6.1.7                    
> py_0    defaults jupyter_console           6.2.0                     
> py_0    defaults jupyter_core              4.6.3                   
> py38_0    defaults jupyterlab                2.2.6                    
> py_0    defaults jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                     
> py_0    defaults jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                     
> py_0    defaults keyring                   21.4.0                  
> py38_1    defaults kiwisolver                1.3.0           
> py38h2531618_0    defaults krb5                      1.18.2           
> h173b8e3_0    defaults lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3           
> py38h7b6447c_0    defaults lcms2                     2.11             
> h396b838_0    defaults ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1              
> h53a641e_7    defaults libarchive                3.4.2               
> h62408e4_0    defaults libcurl                   7.71.1              
> h20c2e04_1    defaults libedit                   3.1.20191231        
> h14c3975_1    defaults libffi                    3.3                 
> he6710b0_2    defaults libgcc-ng                 9.1.0               
> hdf63c60_0    defaults libgfortran-ng            7.3.0               
> hdf63c60_0    defaults liblief                   0.10.1              
> he6710b0_0    defaults libllvm10                 10.0.1              
> hbcb73fb_5    defaults libllvm9                  9.0.1               
> h4a3c616_1    defaults libpng                    1.6.37              
> hbc83047_0    defaults libsodium                 1.0.18              
> h7b6447c_0    defaults libspatialindex           1.9.3               
> he6710b0_0    defaults libssh2                   1.9.0               
> h1ba5d50_1    defaults libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0               
> hdf63c60_0    defaults libtiff                   4.1.0               
> h2733197_1    defaults libtool                   2.4.6            
> h7b6447c_1005    defaults libuuid                   1.0.3             
> h1bed415_2    defaults libxcb                    1.14                
> h7b6447c_0    defaults libxml2                   2.9.10              
> hb55368b_3    defaults libxslt                   1.1.34              
> hc22bd24_0    defaults llvmlite                  0.34.0          
> py38h269e1b5_4    defaults locket                    0.2.0            
> py38_1    defaults lxml                      4.6.1           
> py38hefd8a0e_0    defaults lz4-c                     1.9.2            
> heb0550a_3    defaults lzo                       2.10                
> h7b6447c_2    defaults markupsafe                1.1.1           
> py38h7b6447c_0    defaults matplotlib                3.3.2            
> 0    defaults matplotlib-base           3.3.2           
> py38h817c723_0    defaults mccabe                    0.6.1            
> py38_1    defaults mistune                   0.8.4          
> py38h7b6447c_1000    defaults mkl                       2020.2        
> 256    defaults mkl-service               2.3.0           
> py38he904b0f_0    defaults mkl_fft                   1.2.0           
> py38h23d657b_0    defaults mkl_random                1.1.1           
> py38h0573a6f_0    defaults mock                      4.0.2            
> py_0    defaults more-itertools            8.6.0             
> pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults mpc                       1.1.0              
> h10f8cd9_1    defaults mpfr                      4.0.2               
> hb69a4c5_1    defaults mpmath                    1.1.0                
> py38_0    defaults msgpack-python            1.0.0           
> py38hfd86e86_1    defaults multipledispatch          0.6.0            
> py38_0    defaults navigator-updater         0.2.1                   
> py38_0    defaults nbclient                  0.5.1                    
> py_0    defaults nbconvert                 6.0.7                   
> py38_0    defaults nbformat                  5.0.8                    
> py_0    defaults ncurses                   6.2                 
> he6710b0_1    defaults nest-asyncio              1.4.2             
> pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults networkx                  2.5                
> py_0    defaults nltk                      3.5                       
> py_0    defaults nose                      1.3.7                   
> py38_2    defaults notebook                  6.1.4                   
> py38_0    defaults numba                     0.51.2          
> py38h0573a6f_1    defaults numexpr                   2.7.1           
> py38h423224d_0    defaults numpy                     1.19.2          
> py38h54aff64_0    defaults numpy-base                1.19.2          
> py38hfa32c7d_0    defaults numpydoc                  1.1.0            
> pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults olefile                   0.46               
> py_0    defaults openpyxl                  3.0.5                     
> py_0    defaults openssl                   1.1.1h              
> h7b6447c_0    defaults packaging                 20.4                 
> py_0    defaults pandas                    1.1.3           
> py38he6710b0_0    defaults pandoc                    2.11             
> hb0f4dca_0    defaults pandocfilters             1.4.3           
> py38h06a4308_1    defaults pango                     1.45.3           
> hd140c19_0    defaults parso                     0.7.0                
> py_0    defaults partd                     1.1.0                     
> py_0    defaults patchelf                  0.12                
> he6710b0_0    defaults path                      15.0.0               
> py38_0    defaults path.py                   12.5.0                   
> 0    defaults pathlib2                  2.3.5                   
> py38_0    defaults pathtools                 0.1.2                    
> py_1    defaults patsy                     0.5.1                   
> py38_0    defaults pcre                      8.44                
> he6710b0_0    defaults pep8                      1.7.1                
> py38_0    defaults pexpect                   4.8.0                   
> py38_0    defaults pickleshare               0.7.5                
> py38_1000    defaults pillow                    8.0.1           
> py38he98fc37_0    defaults pip                       20.2.4          
> py38h06a4308_0    defaults pixman                    0.40.0           
> h7b6447c_0    defaults pkginfo                   1.6.1           
> py38h06a4308_0    defaults pluggy                    0.13.1           
> py38_0    defaults ply                       3.11                    
> py38_0    defaults prometheus_client         0.8.0                    
> py_0    defaults prompt-toolkit            3.0.8                     
> py_0    defaults prompt_toolkit            3.0.8                      
> 0    defaults psutil                    5.7.2           
> py38h7b6447c_0    defaults ptyprocess                0.6.0            
> py38_0    defaults py                        1.9.0                    
> py_0    defaults py-lief                   0.10.1          
> py38h403a769_0    defaults pycodestyle               2.6.0            
> py_0    defaults pycosat                   0.6.3           
> py38h7b6447c_1    defaults pycparser                 2.20             
> py_2    defaults pycurl                    7.43.0.6        
> py38h1ba5d50_0    defaults pydocstyle                5.1.1            
> py_0    defaults pyflakes                  2.2.0                     
> py_0    defaults pygments                  2.7.2             
> pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults pylint                    2.6.0              
> py38_0    defaults pyodbc                    4.0.30          
> py38he6710b0_0    defaults pyopenssl                 19.1.0           
> py_1    defaults pyparsing                 2.4.7                     
> py_0    defaults pyqt                      5.9.2           
> py38h05f1152_4    defaults pyrsistent                0.17.3          
> py38h7b6447c_0    defaults pysocks                   1.7.1            
> py38_0    defaults pytables                  3.6.1           
> py38h9fd0a39_0    defaults pytest                    6.1.1            
> py38_0    defaults python                    3.8.5               
> h7579374_1    defaults python-dateutil           2.8.1                
> py_0    defaults python-jsonrpc-server     0.4.0                     
> py_0    defaults python-language-server    0.35.1                    
> py_0    defaults python-libarchive-c       2.9                       
> py_0    defaults pytz                      2020.1                    
> py_0    defaults pywavelets                1.1.1           
> py38h7b6447c_2    defaults pyxdg                     0.27             
> pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults pyyaml                    5.3.1           
> py38h7b6447c_1    defaults pyzmq                     19.0.2          
> py38he6710b0_1    defaults qdarkstyle                2.8.1            
> py_0    defaults qt                        5.9.7               
> h5867ecd_1    defaults qtawesome                 1.0.1                
> py_0    defaults qtconsole                 4.7.7                     
> py_0    defaults qtpy                      1.9.0                     
> py_0    defaults readline                  8.0                 
> h7b6447c_0    defaults regex                     2020.10.15      
> py38h7b6447c_0    defaults requests                  2.24.0           
> py_0    defaults ripgrep                   12.1.1                     
> 0    defaults rope                      0.18.0                    
> py_0    defaults rtree                     0.9.4                   
> py38_1    defaults ruamel_yaml               0.15.87         
> py38h7b6447c_1    defaults scikit-image              0.17.2          
> py38hdf5156a_0    defaults scikit-learn              0.23.2          
> py38h0573a6f_0    defaults scipy                     1.5.2           
> py38h0b6359f_0    defaults seaborn                   0.11.0           
> py_0    defaults secretstorage             3.1.2                   
> py38_0    defaults send2trash                1.5.0                   
> py38_0    defaults setuptools                50.3.1          
> py38h06a4308_1    defaults simplegeneric             0.8.1            
> py38_2    defaults singledispatch            3.4.0.3                
> py_1001    defaults sip                       4.19.13         
> py38he6710b0_0    defaults six                       1.15.0          
> py38h06a4308_0    defaults snappy                    1.1.8            
> he6710b0_0    defaults snowballstemmer           2.0.0                
> py_0    defaults sortedcollections         1.2.1                     
> py_0    defaults sortedcontainers          2.2.2                     
> py_0    defaults soupsieve                 2.0.1                     
> py_0    defaults sphinx                    3.2.1                     
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib             1.0                     
> py38_1    defaults sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2                    
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2                     
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.3                     
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                     
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3                     
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.4                  
> py_0    defaults sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.2.4                     
> py_0    defaults spyder                    4.1.5                   
> py38_0    defaults spyder-kernels            1.9.4                   
> py38_0    defaults sqlalchemy                1.3.20          
> py38h7b6447c_0    defaults sqlite                    3.33.0           
> h62c20be_0    defaults statsmodels               0.12.0          
> py38h7b6447c_0    defaults sympy                     1.6.2           
> py38h06a4308_1    defaults tbb                       2020.3           
> hfd86e86_0    defaults tblib                     1.7.0                
> py_0    defaults terminado                 0.9.1                   
> py38_0    defaults testpath                  0.4.4                    
> py_0    defaults threadpoolctl             2.1.0             
> pyh5ca1d4c_0    defaults tifffile                  2020.10.1       
> py38hdd07704_2    defaults tk                        8.6.10           
> hbc83047_0    defaults toml                      0.10.1               
> py_0    defaults toolz                     0.11.1                    
> py_0    defaults tornado                   6.0.4           
> py38h7b6447c_1    defaults tqdm                      4.50.2           
> py_0    defaults traitlets                 5.0.5                     
> py_0    defaults typing_extensions         3.7.4.3                   
> py_0    defaults ujson                     4.0.1           
> py38he6710b0_0    defaults unicodecsv                0.14.1           
> py38_0    defaults unixodbc                  2.3.9               
> h7b6447c_0    defaults urllib3                   1.25.11              
> py_0    defaults watchdog                  0.10.3                  
> py38_0    defaults wcwidth                   0.2.5                    
> py_0    defaults webencodings              0.5.1                   
> py38_1    defaults werkzeug                  1.0.1                    
> py_0    defaults wheel                     0.35.1                    
> py_0    defaults widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                   
> py38_0    defaults wrapt                     1.11.2          
> py38h7b6447c_0    defaults wurlitzer                 2.0.1            
> py38_0    defaults xlrd                      1.2.0                    
> py_0    defaults xlsxwriter                1.3.7                     
> py_0    defaults xlwt                      1.3.0                   
> py38_0    defaults xmltodict                 0.12.0                   
> py_0    defaults xz                        5.2.5               
> h7b6447c_0    defaults yaml                      0.2.5               
> h7b6447c_0    defaults yapf                      0.30.0               
> py_0    defaults zeromq                    4.3.3               
> he6710b0_3    defaults zict                      2.0.0                
> py_0    defaults zipp                      3.4.0             
> pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults zlib                      1.2.11             
> h7b6447c_3    defaults zope                      1.0                  
> py38_1    defaults zope.event                4.5.0                   
> py38_0    defaults zope.interface            5.1.2           
> py38h7b6447c_0    defaults zstd                      1.4.5            
> h9ceee32_0    defaults
> ````

but when i tried to install the Jupyter [by `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab` command](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html) i get this error:

```
(base) so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~/Downloads$  conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
 path: /home/so/.conda/pkgs/urls.txt
 uid: 1000
 gid: 1000

If you feel that permissions on this path are set incorrectly, you can manually
change them by executing

 $ sudo chown 1000:1000 /home/so/.conda/pkgs/urls.txt

In general, it's not advisable to use 'sudo conda'.
```

And i have understand the **/home/so/.conda/pkgs** folder is not exist as you can see below:

```
(base) so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~$ cd /home/so/.conda/pkgs
bash: cd: /home/so/.conda/pkgs: No such file or directory
```

So what do you suggest to solve this problem?

**Update:**

I have **found solution** and write it as **answer** to this question for other usage, But I **don't know** why by **removing the** 'username:` part of the above command , like said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588497/sudo-conda-command-not-found) and shown below, it was not working?

```
(base) so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~$ sudo chmod -R +x /home/so/anaconda3
(base) so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~$ sudo chmod -R +x /home/so/.conda
(base) so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~$ conda update --all
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: /home/so/.conda/pkgs/urls.txt
  uid: 1000
  gid: 1000

If you feel that permissions on this path are set incorrectly, you can manually
change them by executing

  $ sudo chown 1000:1000 /home/so/.conda/pkgs/urls.txt

In general, it's not advisable to use 'sudo conda'.
```

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It was the **conda** **permission problem**  and based of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726184/missing-write-permissions-in-home-user-anaconda2) post and its answers, I tried these commands:

```
so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~$ sudo chown -R so: /home/so/anaconda3
so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~$ sudo chown -R so: /home/so/.conda
```

And my problem as you can see below solved:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Which means you erroneously ran `sudo conda` in the past; don't do that.

Comment: So it means by using `sudo conda` it have locked the `anaconda3` and `.conda` folder?

Comment: That's one thing which can happen if the directories did not exist when you ran `sudo conda`; when you run it privileged, any files or directories it creates will belong to `root`. You should basically never have files which belong to someone else in your home directory (and vice versa, really).