# Error processing line 1 of /Users/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vision-1.0.0-py3.7-nspkg.pth

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed few different packages including manim, jupyter-manim but now I am keep getting this error on the terminal after any command:

```
Error processing line 1 of /Users/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vision-1.0.0-py3.7-nspkg.pth:
```

I uninstalled `manim , jupyter-manim` but the error does not go away.

I also tried to `conda update --all` to update my python but that does not work either.

I am running on Mac Catalina, Anaconda Python 3.7.5
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is probably conflict with matplotlib. So run this command from cmd:

```
conda remove --name root matplotlib

conda install python="your version" matplotlib
```

Source is [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9876)

Comment: the error on the other post is related to matplotlib but in my case is related to vision; the errors are not the same

Comment: This accordingly means  conda detected conflict with specified package version.

Comment: Another thing you can do  updating conda  using `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`

Comment: I replaced matplotlib with vision in your suggested solution but does not work.  I also tried updating conda the way you suggested. conda was updated successfully but the original error remains

Comment: Could you please post full error message since it is not really clear what the error is, for instance, is it attribute error or import error...

Comment: sure, I added the screen-shot to the original post

Comment: i have found one solutiion. Basically you make a change in the first line  of this  `vision-1.0.0-py3.7-nspkg.pth` file(in your case it is first line i guess).you will see m = has_mfs  or has_mfs = sys.version_info`. Add a new linebreak before them. Source is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935698/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-loader) and [link](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/95)

Comment: If this does not work, just delete this `vision-1.0.0-py3.7-nspkg.pth` file. It also  mentioned in one of source i shared

Comment: thanks, linebreak in pth file did not work. I ended up deleting the file and the error is gone. I am not sure though what the purpose of that pth file is and how it may affect other thing in the future

Comment: In the official pypi.org it says , `this package is present in the Public PyPi repositories to prevent package conflicts between Open Source Python packages and Verizon Media internal packages` so I have found these three packages for python implementation in their github page: `py-ectoken`, `frisky`, `beeswithmachineguns`. Check out which might affect...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230991/discussion-between-user20210310-and-a-e).