# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.colors',

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

When I try to launch jupyter notebook, I get this from anaconda prompt
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSTLS.jpg)

after launching jupyter notebook, I get this on anaconda prompt before jupyter notebook opens in browser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s3Wf.jpg)

after running the following import code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import seaborn as sn
    from sklearn import datasets
    from sklearn import metrics
    from sklearn import tree
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
```

i get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6884\4230379327.py in <module>
      4 import pandas as pd
      5 import numpy as np
----> 6 import seaborn as sn
      7 from sklearn import datasets
      8 from sklearn import metrics

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py in <module>
      1 # Import seaborn objects
----> 2 from .rcmod import *  # noqa: F401,F403
      3 from .utils import *  # noqa: F401,F403
      4 from .palettes import *  # noqa: F401,F403
      5 from .relational import *  # noqa: F401,F403

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py in <module>
      5 import matplotlib as mpl
      6 from cycler import cycler
----> 7 from . import palettes
      8 
      9 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py in <module>
      7 from .external import husl
      8 
----> 9 from .utils import desaturate, get_color_cycle
     10 from .colors import xkcd_rgb, crayons
     11 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py in <module>
     11 import pandas as pd
     12 import matplotlib as mpl
---> 13 import matplotlib.colors as mplcol
     14 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     15 from matplotlib.cbook import normalize_kwargs

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.colors'
```

when i comment the line giving the above error `#import seaborn as sn` i get the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6884\1207372402.py in <module>
      8 from sklearn import metrics
      9 from sklearn import tree
---> 10 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
     11 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
     12 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

ImportError: cannot import name 'DecisionTreeClassifier' from 'sklearn.tree' (unknown location)
```

when I run `pip list`, it shows that I have both seaborn 0.11.2 and scikitlearn 1.0.2 installed.
what could be wrong and how do i fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935698/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-loader)

Comment: My suggestion is to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda

Comment: @EvgenyKovalev the problem discussed looks similar to mine but I don't understand the solution provided. where do I edit the code?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney yeah will do that as a last resort if I cant fix it. thanks.

Comment: @Ty_Ronmi I do not understand the error, so I would suggest to experiment with solutions from Google. You have a problem with some .pth file from Anaconda. Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59939197/11347890 You can try to do similar things, but with your .pth file from error message.