# answer How can I solve this kernal error in Jupyter on anaconda

Tags: anaconda, conda

I didn't change anything but today i got this error when i try to use conda.

```
Error processing line 3 of D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\googleapis_common_protos-1.53.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\anaconda\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 553, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935698/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-loader

Answer (score 0):

edit googleapis_common_protos-1.53.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth

search for "os;" and add a carriage return after it.