# Python error vision-1.0.0-py3.10-nspkg.pth:

Tags: python

Whenever I run python I get this error message:
Error processing line 1 of D:\Users\RBS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\vision-1.0.0-py3.10-nspkg.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Users\RBS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 186, in addpackage
exec(line)
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 568, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
What is this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds a lot like what I saw at: [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935698/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-loader)

Based on their comments what worked for me was going to C:\Users\"username"\anaconda3\envs\"Project name" then looking for a file called "vision-1.0.0-py3.7-nspkg.pth" and deleting it.

Ran into this post before having seen the other one, thought I'd share. Solved the error for me but not sure if removing the files would give any sort of problem later on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).