# Is there a way to stop namespace package (*-nspkg.pth) files from being one, excessively long line, or reformat them automatically?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a Python-based website, running on AWS servers (so on Amazon's modified Linux).
The website is deployed using AWS Code Pipeline. So the site is built automatically before deploy. And scripts injected via Python's deploy hooks restart Apache and uwsgi after deploy.

Something inevitably generates or installs .pth files.
If the website directory is `.`, then the .pth files are `./lib/python3.8/site-packages/*-nspkg.pth`.
Those .pth files inevitably break the site, by causing uwsgi to fail to start with "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'whatever'". It fails, because the file content is apparently one excessively long line that it (pip?) can't read. The solution to deal with them is apparently to delete them or edit them to add line spaces after every semicolon. ([AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935698/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-loader))
I'm not sure when these files recur; maybe when something is forced to reinstall? It's not every time that the site auto-rebuilds and deploys.

What is creating these? Can I avoid it? Or can I make the thing stop writing them as a single line that is too long to be successfully parsed?

I'm adding a line to CodeDeploy's AfterInstall script that will hopefully just always delete them. (I'm selectively deleting only the "top-level" *-nspkg.pth files directly related to the platform I'm using or its plugins.) I need to test it still, though I presume it will work. But, still, I'd like to know if something in Python/pip/setuptools can just be told to not be stupid. And I'd definitely like to know how or when they're probably being generated.

Comment: Now I'm learning there are definitely times that installation fails because the .pth files are not there, and it leads to ModuleNotFoundError, since `python setup.py develop` can't find itself. Dumb. And that whatever reads the files only executes lines starting with "import".